# global action for visual force page not appearing the navigation menu

Tags: visualforce, global-actions

I have created a global action created - visual force page. But when cant find the global action to Action drop down list in the navigation menu .Since the visual force page doesnt use a standard controller or any controller,there should not be an issue . But not sure what is happening .Any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_navigationmenuitem.htm) (refer 'Type field) ,  Global actions are only supported for Create Record in Navigation Menu. Also, I see similar behavior in my org as well.

Thanks